Received an internal server error from Apple's App Store Connect
Does anyone know how to solve this? I am in the latest eas CLI. I am doing eas build -p ios... I am able to log into App Store Connect normally through the GUI, but not through the CLI.
✖ Logging in...
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Received an internal server error from Apple's App Store Connect / Developer Portal servers, please try again later. Apple service errors:

Verification codes can’t be sent to this phone number at this time. Please try again later.
If you encounter persistent issues with Apple 2FA SMS authentication, you can try using these workarounds: https://expo.fyi/apple-2fa-sms-issues-workaround.md.
Error: build command failed.

I've tried upgrading eas -g cli, I've tried generating the certificate and the API key manually, and nothing has worked.

Apple has increased their security making EAS CLI integration fail the SMS authentication. This has been reported here: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/apple-2fa-sms-issues-workaround.md
Solution 12/12/24: Log into your Apple account from an Apple device where you will receive the security code to authenticate the EAS CLI. SMS no longer works
